Showing sidebar based on the context?
When the user logs in to my website, they see the main dashboard. They can navigate to the Projects page and see a list of projects.
I am planning to put the Dashboard, Projects, global Settings etc links in the top nav bar.
When they click on a specific project, they see project specific dashboard. They can navigate to Assets, project specific Settings, etc pages from the sidebar.
Now, the sidebar does not come into picture until they click on a project. Where should the sidebar go on rest of the global (i.e. top nav) pages?

Hide the sidebar
Show the sidebar with empty content? (tried this out but it does look a bit odd)

or is there a better UI/UX pattern for this usecase?
Just for reference, here's the Projects page with the sidebar content hidden:



The content hierarchy should be changed to something like this. Having both the sidebar and the projects at the same level of hierarchy will be wrong given that the sidebar is specific to a project and does not apply to all the projects.
